# How to escape a character in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a txt file like this.

```
    PersonA , "3115,Clark Street Buford, GA 30518"
    PersonB , "1656, Ashley Court Ridgefield, CT 06877"
```

And I need to load this data into pig (The delimiter should be a ",").
How to do this? How to check for the commas inside the address?

And the output should be like this.

```
PersonA , "3115,Clark Street Buford, GA 30518"
PersonB , "1656, Ashley Court Ridgefield, CT 06877"
```

But the produced output is.

```
  PersonA , "3115
  PersonB , "1656
```

Comment: Why should the delimiter be ','? Looks like the input and output are same.In that case,why use a delimiter?Can't you just load the rows in the input file into one field as a line:chararray?

Comment: While there are probably tricks that can solve your problem, honestly the best solution would be to change the input file to use a different delimiter, like pipes or colons.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use Regular Expression command ie..**REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL()**

Code for this :

```
a = LOAD '<path_Of_File>' as line;

b = FOREACH a GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)[,](.*)'))  AS (f1,f2);

dump b;
```